# WordPress sidebar: query specific pages based on current page

Tags: wordpress, templates, sidebar

I have three pages in my WordPress site: About, Voices & History. These are all using the same template. Each of these are parent pages to several additional respective sub-pages (i.e. About is parent to five About sub-pages). All of the parent pages use the same sidebar.php file.

Is it possible for the sidebar to display only the parent's respective sub-pages?

For example, if the user is on the About page, the sidebar would query and only display About sub-pages. If they're on the Voices page, the sidebar changes to display only Voices sub-pages.

I've been unsuccessful in my attempts. Any code to accomplish this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is, in you loop do this:

```
<?php
//calling loop stuff here
// bla bla
// stores post that will have related posts
global $related;
$related = $post->ID;
// end loop
?>
```

Then, in your sidebar you do this:

```
<?php
//common sidebar stuff here
//bla bla
//check if has related posts
global $related;
if (!empty($related)) {
//call related posts here
}
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to get this working; I'm sure I'm doing something wrong. Where exactly do I put the first code block in my page template? What should I put inside the second code block's "//call related posts here"?